# The stored procedure in the query

Tags: mysql

There is a procedure **GetFileList** - returns, as the name implies, a list of files and a couple more options with them.

Is it possible then to use this procedure in the query select?

Something like this: `select Field1 from Image where Field2 IN (call GetFileList ());`

Comment: This is impossible, as far as I know.
very simple - the procedure to fill a temporary table
use it in the query. as an option - to return a string with the ID (s) and
parse in SQL - the truth is through the "anus".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should change it to a function
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3569846/MySQL-Stored-Functions.htm