# Return array in stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I am trying to use the result of a stored function in a WHERE statement in MySQL (5.x), but it fails because in the function I am selecting values from a table into an INT variable and then returning them/it, which obviously doesn't work if the SELECT returns more than 1 row. I've tried returning a TABLE (as I understood TABLE means array in MySQL) but that didn't work either.

Is there any way that I could do something like:

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE ID IN my_function(params);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done...

First, you cannot use a stored function to return multiple results - you would need to use a stored procedure.

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) state:

> Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored procedure but not within a stored function.

Second, you cannot use a stored procedure in a query - see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840265/the-stored-procedure-in-the-query).

Have you considered using 'HAVING ...' at the end of your query?

Comment: ok so now i have something like `CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(IN param INT, OUT result TABLE)` which doesn't work also, it fails at the TABLE keyword

Comment: No - the syntax for creating a stored procedure is different. I've amended my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Yes, I've had something like that too, but the problem is, I can't use that in a WHERE statement. Something like `SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id IN (CALL isLessThan(5))`

Comment: @amaidment, I'm trying your example above, but it falls over with an error over the CALL statement. How did you get this to work?

Comment: @Cpat - actually, it turns out that you cannot use a stored procedure in a select query. Amended accordingly...